# Smaller font for < sign

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I have a table where i report times.
Some elements are very small and I would like to write $<1\mathrm{ms}$.
However, if I do so, the < 1ms will occupy even more space than a three digit number which looks a bit out of place.

Apart foom that, I could really need the extra space to keep my table small.

What would be the appropriate way to have the less then sign appear as part of the number and not as operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${\scriptstyle<}1\mathrm{ms}$` perhaps?